# If a double integral is bounded below by a $+\infty$ double integral, is it also $+\infty?$

Tags: integration, divergent-integrals

If we have two functions $f,g$ defined on a region $R$ such that $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y),$ for all $(x,y) \in R,$ we can guarantee that
$$ \iint_R f(x,y) dA \leq \iint_R g(x,y)dA. $$
This is a well-known fact.

Now, assume that we can also guarantee that
$$ \iint_R f(x,y)dA = +\infty$$
Can we also guarantee that
$$ \iint_R g(x,y)dA \overbrace{=}^{?} +\infty  $$
If so, what is the reasoning behind this?
Sometimes I get quite confused when it comes to infinity.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, $$ \iint_R f(x,y)dA = +\infty$$ means something like "For an arbitrarily large number $N\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there is some partition of $R$ into smaller parts $R_1,\dots,R_n$ (such that $R=\cup_i R_i$) and numbers $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ such that $f(x)>\lambda_i$ for $x\in R_i$, and $N<\sum_i \lambda_i A(R_i)$, where $A(R_i)$ is the area of the region $R_i$."

(The precise definition depends on your type of integration. esp. using Riemann integration, you should also split out positive and negative, and then the regions $R_i$ should be rectangles.)

The point here is that $\sum_i \lambda_i\mathbf{1}_{R_i}$ is an *approximation* of $f$ by a *simple function*, and in particular a lower bound.

Although this is a bit technical, your question quickly follows: When $f\leq g$, then for any big $N$ and any "approximation" $\sum_i\lambda_i\mathbf{1}_{R_i}$ of $f$ such that $N<\sum_i\lambda_iA(R_i)$, we also have that $ g(x)>\lambda_i$ for $x\in R_i$, so this "approximation" also approximates/is a lower bound of $g$, so indeed $$ \iint_R g(x,y)dA = +\infty$$

Comment: Hello! I think I understood your process of thought. Can you check if this alternative procedure also makes sense? Assuming we already know that $$ \iint_R f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = +\infty.$$ If the integral of $g$ over $R$ was convergent (i.e., if the integral is a finite value) then an immediate contradiction would yield - recall the inequality presented would be equivalent to $$ \iint_R f(x,y) \, dA \leqslant \iint_R g(x,y) \, dA \Leftrightarrow +\infty \leqslant \iint_R g(x,y) \, dA. $$ then, as I said, an immediate contradiction yields (a fixed value isn't bigger than infinity).

Comment: Thus, the integral $$ \iint_R g(x,y) \, dA $$ must be divergent.

Comment: Well, I believe you only know $$\iint_R f(x,y)\mathrm{d}A\leq\iint_R g(x,y)\mathrm{d}A$$ if both these integrals converge. For example, if $\iint f dA$ does _not_ converge (not even to $+\infty$) e.g. $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\sin(y)$ with $R=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $g\geq f$ everywhere, then you do not know if $\iint g dA=+\infty$ or not. Now if $\iint f dA$ does _not_ converge to a real number, but to $+\infty$, you cannot just use the theorem for real numbers, you have to prove it again from the definition of integral, as I did (hand-wavingly, b.c. I don't know your definition).

Comment: I think it's true even if they diverge. Are you sure it's only valid when they converge?

Comment: It can very well be true if they diverge, but the question is, do you _know_ if this is true? Mathemathics isn't very much about what's true or not. It's more about what you _know_ to be true or false (i.e. what you can prove to be true/false). I assumed your book had a proof for the inequality when both converge, and I showed how to _prove_ it in the case that they diverged.